# Easy Responsive Tabs Plugin: Author: Samson.Onna need some modification

Tags: tabs

## Please help me i implemented this js but I have problem when I call an event body click the tab content will also hide...

I used this code but problem is when i click on tab button its already hide..

```
 $('body').click(function(e){
 $('.resp-tabs-container').hide();
});
```

### My HTML FILE

```
<div id="verticalTab">
      <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
        <li class="first flights"><em class="sprite">&nbsp;</em>Book a Flight</li>
        <li class="rooms"><em class="sprite">&nbsp;</em>Book Hotel Rooms</li>
        <li class="tickets"><em class="sprite">&nbsp;</em>Book Movie Tickets</li>
        <li class="vouchers"><em class="sprite">&nbsp;</em>Book Vouchers</li>
        <li class="new"><em class="sprite">&nbsp;</em>What's New</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="resp-tabs-container"> 
        <!--Book A Flight-->
        <div>
          <div class="tabForm">
            <form action="">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="rowG select-opt flatui">
                  <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="tripOpt" checked="checked" />
                    <label>One Way</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="tripOpt" />
                    <label>Round Trip</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="tripOpt" />
                    <label>Multiple Destinations</label>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="rowG clearfix">
                  <div class="col">
                    <label>Leaving From</label>
                    <input type="text" class="field" value="Location">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <label>Departure Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="field date-field" value="DD/MM/YY">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col selectdd">
                    <label>Time</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>Any</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rowG clearfix">
                  <div class="col">
                    <label>Going To</label>
                    <input type="text" class="field" value="Location">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rowG clearfix">
                  <div class="col selectdd">
                    <label>Adult (18-64)</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col selectdd">
                    <label>Seniors (65+)</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col selectdd">
                    <label>Children</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rowG clearfix"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#showAdditionalData" id="showAdditional" class="i-arrowup" href="#">Show Additional Options<span id="toggler" class="icon-chevron-left" ></span></a>
                  <div class="contents addpaddingT10">
                    <div id="showAdditionalData" class="collapse">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label>Preferred Airline</label>
                        <select>
                          <option>No Preference</option>
                        </select>
                        <p class="addpaddingT10">
                        <div class="flatui">
                        <input type="checkbox"/><label>Nonstop Flights Only</label>
                         </div>                             
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col">
                        <label>Class</label>
                        <select>
                          <option>First Class</option>
                        </select>
                        <p class="addpaddingT10">   
                           <div class="flatui">
                             <input type="checkbox"/><label>Refundable Flights Only</label>
                         </div>                        
                         </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rowG last clearfix">
                  <p class="floatL">
                  <div class="flatui">
                             <input type="checkbox"/><label>Redeem PR Points for this booking</label>
                         </div> 

                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-icon floatR" value="Search">
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Flight book--> 
        <!--Hotel booking-->
        <div>
          <div class="tabFormHotel">
            <form action="">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="rowG">
                  <label>Destination, hotel, landmark or address</label>
                  <input type="text" class="large" value="A city, airport or attraction">
                </div>
                <div class="rowG clearfix">
                  <div class="col">
                    <label>Check In</label>
                    <input type="text" class="field date-field" value="DD/MM/YYYY">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <label>Check Out</label>
                    <input type="text" class="field date-field" value="DD/MM/YYYY">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <label>Rooms</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker">
                      <option>Any</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rowG clearfix selectdd">
                  <legend>Room 1</legend>
                  <div class="c1">
                    <label>Adult <span>(12+ years)</span></label>
                    <select>                         
                      <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="c1 selectdd">
                    <label>Child <span>(2-11 years)</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="c2 selectdd">
                    <label>Child 1 Age</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>2</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="c2 selectdd">
                    <label>Child 2 Age</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>6</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="c2 selectdd">
                    <label>Child 3 Age</label>
                    <select>
                      <option>8</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rowG last clearfix">
                  <p class="floatL">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label>Redeem PR Points for this booking</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-icon floatR" value="Search">
                  </p>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Hotel-->
        <div>
          <p>Book Movie Tickets</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Book Vouchers</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>What's New</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### Here is the JS which i used

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.extend({
    easyResponsiveTabs: function (options) {
        //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
        var defaults = {
            type: 'default', //default, vertical, accordion;
            width: 'auto',
            fit: true
        }
        //Variables
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);            
        var opt = options, jtype = opt.type, jfit = opt.fit, jwidth = opt.width, vtabs = 'vertical', accord = 'accordion';

        //Main function
        this.each(function () {
            var $respTabs = $(this);
            $respTabs.find('ul.resp-tabs-list li').addClass('resp-tab-item');
            $respTabs.css({
                'display': 'block',
                'width': jwidth
            });

            $respTabs.find('.resp-tabs-container > div').addClass('resp-tab-content');
            jtab_options();
            //Properties Function
            function jtab_options() {
                if (jtype == vtabs) {
                    $respTabs.addClass('resp-vtabs');
                }
                if (jfit == true) {
                    $respTabs.css({ width: '100%', margin: '0px' });
                }
                if (jtype == accord) {
                    $respTabs.addClass('resp-easy-accordion');
                    $respTabs.find('.resp-tabs-list').css('display', 'none');
                }
            }

            //Assigning the h2 markup to accordion title
            var $tabItemh2;
            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content').before("<h2 class='resp-accordion' role='tab'><span class='resp-arrow'></span></h2>");

            var itemCount = 0;
            $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion').each(function () {
                $tabItemh2 = $(this);
                var innertext = $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-item:eq(' + itemCount + ')').html();
                $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion:eq(' + itemCount + ')').append(innertext);
                $tabItemh2.attr('aria-controls', 'tab_item-' + (itemCount));
                itemCount++;
            });

            //Assigning the 'aria-controls' to Tab items
            var count = 0,
                $tabContent;
            $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-item').each(function () {
                $tabItem = $(this);
                $tabItem.attr('aria-controls', 'tab_item-' + (count));
                $tabItem.attr('role', 'tab');

                //First active tab                   
               // $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-item').first().addClass('resp-tab-active');
                //$respTabs.find('.resp-accordion').first().addClass('resp-tab-active');
                //$respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content').first().addClass('resp-tab-content-active').attr('style', 'display:block');

                //Assigning the 'aria-labelledby' attr to tab-content
                var tabcount = 0;
                $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content').each(function () {
                    $tabContent = $(this);
                    $tabContent.attr('aria-labelledby', 'tab_item-' + (tabcount));
                    tabcount++;
                });
                count++;
            });

            //Tab Click action function
            $respTabs.find("[role=tab]").each(function () {
                var $currentTab = $(this);
                $currentTab.click(function () {

                    var $tabAria = $currentTab.attr('aria-controls');

                    if ($currentTab.hasClass('resp-accordion') && $currentTab.hasClass('resp-tab-active')) {
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content-active').slideUp('', function () { $(this).addClass('resp-accordion-closed'); });
                         $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-active').removeClass('resp-tab-active');                          
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!$currentTab.hasClass('resp-tab-active') && $currentTab.hasClass('resp-accordion')) {
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-active').removeClass('resp-tab-active');
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content-active').slideUp().removeClass('resp-tab-content-active resp-accordion-closed');
                        $respTabs.find("[aria-controls=" + $tabAria + "]").addClass('resp-tab-active');

                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content[aria-labelledby = ' + $tabAria + ']').slideDown().addClass('resp-tab-content-active');
                    } else {
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-active').removeClass('resp-tab-active');
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content-active').removeAttr('style').removeClass('resp-tab-content-active').removeClass('resp-accordion-closed');
                        $respTabs.find("[aria-controls=" + $tabAria + "]").addClass('resp-tab-active');
                        $respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content[aria-labelledby = ' + $tabAria + ']').addClass('resp-tab-content-active').attr('style', 'display:block');
                    }
                });


                //Window resize function                   
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    $respTabs.find('.resp-accordion-closed').removeAttr('style');
                });

            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the follwing javascript to prevent the clicks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("body").click(function(e){
            if (!$(e.target).is('.ui-datepicker,.ui-datepicker *,.ui-icon,.ui-autocomplete,.ui-autocomplete *,.resp-tab-active, .resp-tab-active *, #verticalTab, #verticalTab *')) {
                //$(".resp-tabs-container").hide();                     
                $(".resp-vtabs li").removeClass('resp-tab-active');
                $(".resp-vtabs .resp-tabs-container .resp-tab-content-active").removeClass('resp-tab-content-active').hide();
            }});
    });
    </script>
```